# Why is subclassing goog.ui.Button producing this error?

Tags: google-closure-library

I made a subclass of goog.ui.Button in my Google Closure javascript.

```
/**
 * @fileoverview This button makes a new widget.
 * @author David Faux
 */

goog.provide('app.ui.NewWidgetButton');

goog.require('goog.ui.Button');



/**
 * Button for creating a new widget.
 * @constructor
 * @param {goog.ui.ButtonRenderer=} opt_renderer Optional renderer used to
 *    render or decorate the button.
 * @param {goog.dom.DomHelper=} opt_domHelper Optional DOM hepler, used for
 *    document interaction.
 * @extends {goog.ui.Button}
 */
app.ui.NewWidgetButton = function(opt_renderer, opt_domHelper) {
  goog.base(
    this,
    /** @type {goog.ui.ControlContent} */ 'New Widget',
    opt_renderer,
    opt_domHelper);
}
goog.inherits(app.ui.NewWidgetButton, goog.ui.Button);
```

However, when I instantiate this button with `var newButton = app.ui.NewWidgetButton();`, I get an error in Chrome Console:

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setContentInternal'`
```

I looked up the method `setContentInternal`, and it seemed to be a method of the class `goog.ui.Control`, which is a superclass of `goog.ui.Button`, so I am befuddled as to why this method is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instantiation of `newButton` is missing the `new` keyword. Adding the `new` keyword fixes the error.

```
var newButton = new app.ui.NewWidgetButton();
```

Set the Closure Compiler flag `--warning_level=VERBOSE` to generate an error such as the following:

> WARNING - Constructor function (new:app.ui.NewWidgetButton, (goog.ui.ButtonRenderer|null)=, (goog.dom.DomHelper|null)=): undefined should be called with the "new" keyword

Comment: Thank you, adding new fixed it. However, I still can't get that error to show up when it's broken. I'm using Plovr to compile, and I set this config file to use VERBOSE as the warning level. Do you see anything awry in this config file? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1531353/Misc/Docudocker/config.js

Comment: Compiling with plovr in *server mode* by setting the html script source to `http://0.0.0.0:9810/compile?id=myProjectID`, the warning is generated but plovr never displays it in the browser due to the uncaught TypeError stopping the JavaScript execution prior to reaching the line `plovr.addWarnings([{...}]);`. Try compiling with plovr on the command line in `build mode`, which ensures that all errors and warnings will be displayed irrespective of uncaught execution errors.

Comment: Odd, I was running in build mode with that config file though (piping the generated js into a file). I'm still tinkering with it to get the warnings to display. Thanks!

Comment: In your plovr config file, have you tried specifying the `output-file` property? This will send the compiled JS to the specified file, but still send warnings and errors to standard output.